# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\Lotus\Notes\nlsxbe.dll: Can't load IA 32-bit .dll on a AMD 64-bit platform

Tags: java, eclipse, 32bit-64bit, lotus-domino

I am trying to connect Lotus Notes Domino (8.5.1) objects from a java web application which uses eclipse (indigo, jdk1.7). this is what I did:
 1. add notes.jar to Librairies of Java Build Path in eclipse,
 2. add path variable of "C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\Lotus\Notes" to path of Envrionment variable of my local computer.
then I created this simple java codes in eclipse as below:

```
 import lotus.domino.*;
 public class platform3
{
     public static void main(String argv[])
    {
       try
         {
        NotesThread.sinitThread();
        Session s = NotesFactory.createSession();
        String p = s.getPlatform();
        System.out.println("Platform = " + p);
        }
       catch(Exception e)
       {
        e.printStackTrace();
       }
         finally
       {
      NotesThread.stermThread();
      }
   }
  }
```

The above codes are compiled without any problem, but when I run it, I got this error:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\Lotus\Notes\nlsxbe.dll: Can't load IA 32-bit .dll on a AMD 64-bit platform
I searched from the internet, it seems the Lotus Domino 8.5.1 is 32 bit, and my java project (jdk1.7) is 64bits, so they are not compatible. but I can not change my java (eclipse) to 32bit since I need it to develop 64 bit web projects. 
Does anybody know how to make it work without changing my java from 64bits to 32bits?

Comment: You can not load i386 libraries with 64-bit JVM. Can you not have an i386 JDK installed along side your amd64 JDK - just for this project? There's no problem to have the two of them on the same machine.

Comment: Thanks a lot, as I mentioned in my post, my java web project is a big application, it must be using jdk64bit, besides, my request to connect Lotus is a small requirement, and we may change this requirement to other way if it requires to jdk32bit, I do not want this requirement to have any impacts to my java project.

Answer (score 1):

As @maksimov noted in the comments, a 64 bit JVM cannot load the 32 bit Notes DLLs. There is, howver, a 64 bit version of the DLLs, but you will have to install and configure the Lotus Domino Server (64 bit Windows version) on your machine - and on any machine(s) where the web application will run. You will only have to run the Domino server once per machine in order to get it fully configured. It will not have to be running all the time in order for your code to access the DLLs, but you will have to leave it installed. You will have to, however, check with whomever manages your IBM relationship, and possibly with IBM, in order to determine whether there are any licensing and cost implications before installing the Domino server code this way.  (One further note: in order to get the 64 bit Domino Server code cleanly installed on the machine and insure that that particular version of nlsxbe.dll is the one that your code loads, you will be best off if you uninstall and completely clean the existing 32 bit Notes client installation. And by cleaning, I'd get rid of the lotus.ini file, and any notes.ini files and Notes-related registry entries that might be left over after the uninstallation.)

There is also another option.  Your code is using the "local" version of the Notes Java API in notes.jar. There is also a CORBA/IIOP version of the API, which does not use any Notes or Dominbo DLLs. In fact, it doesn't require any installation of any Lotus code, and it has no licensing implications either. All you need for this is a copy of the NCSO.jar added to your project. You do need to be aware that the capabilities of the NCSO.jar version of the API are slightly different from the local version, code to set up a session is slightly different, authentication does not rely on Notes ID files, and the Domino servers that you connect to must be running the IIOP task - which will not be the case by default, so you may have to negotiate that with the people who manage those servers.

**Note - Removed an update that was suggesting the OpenNTF API as an alternative.** That was a bit of temporary confusion. It could not have helped.

Comment: Hi Richard, it seems it is not easy to make it work. As I mentioned in my post, my java web project is using jdk64bits, this can not change since my lotus connection is a small requirement. And our domino server may not be configured to 64 bits due to this requirement since it impacts to domino used for all company employees, i do not think domino admin will like to do it. CORBA/IIOP also needs configuration of domino server, I do not think admin will like to do it either.

Comment: Are you running the web application on the same machine as the Domino server that is used for the whole company?  I assumed they are different machines, because that is normal. If they are separate machines, then there is no impact at all for everyone else because you can install a 64 bit Domino server on the web application machine and leave 32 bit on the main Domino server. As I said, you don't even have to run the 64 bit server except for one time in order to configure it. After that, it can stay shut down but your web app code can still use the 64 bit Domino API DLLs.

Comment: Domino 64 bit DLLs will have no problem talking to the 32 bit Domino server. Domino software is designed to interoperate no matter what the version, OS and bit size. If the machines are separate, the only thing you have to do is check into the licensing issue to see if there is any cost to your organization for installing an additional copy of the server software. In reality, it is not even operating as a server; it is only installed to be the client-side API DLL for your web app, but only IBM can tell you what the licensing implications are.

Comment: Thanks a lot again for your help, for our case, the Java Web application is sitting in a different server machine from domino server. So basically, let's our Domino server 32 bit machine is sitting on Server1, and my Java web application is sitting on Server2, then I have to install Domino (8.5.1) 64 bits server on Server2 in order to make my Java web app to user notes.jar(64bits) file. As I mentioned, considering for the licensing issue and we need to maintain a seperate Domino 64 bits server even we do not need to run it, we may think for other approach.

Comment: I have updated my answer with one more option. I do not know if it will help you or not, but the OpenNTF Domino API is an open source replacement for Notes.jar, and the team that is working on it may have designed it for compatibility with both 32 and 64 bit JVMs and 32 and 64 bit Notes DLLs. It is worth checking into. I put several links into my updated answer.

Comment: thanks for the updates, that is a good option, I just did a quick search for note.dll and nlsxbe.dll, it seems I can not find them in OpenNTF site, please let me know if you can find it. I really appreciate your help,

Comment: No,  you can't find the DLLS there. You can find the jar file for the openNTF version of the API there. It is a replacement for Notes.jar. But thinking more clearly now, there's really no way they could have solved this either. You have to have the DLLS that match the bitness of the JVM, and the only legal way to get them is to install the WIN64 Domino Server code.

Comment: thanks a lot for your quick response, if that is the only legal way, then I may think of other approach instead of saving my date in Lotus database by installing the WIN64 Domino Server code. thanks again.

Comment: Hi Richard, just confirmed with my notes admin, our domino is running both: 32bits and 64 bits, so it seems I have 64 bits domino server, but based on your post, I need to install my domino server to the server of my java web application is running. The second question is that, the Notes.dll and nlsxbe.dll are located on my local notes client, I copied notes.dll to my java web library, and create a path to point to nlsxe.dll on my local, I donot understand why should I still use Domino server 64 bits to be installed on my java web project server?can you explain more? thanks

Comment: The simple answer is that any other configuration is unsupported and probably won't work. The code has been designed and tested by IBM to work in its installed configuration, and millions of people use that configuration so you can have very high assurance that it will work correctly. In any other configuration, that is not the case. It might work. It might not. It might appear to mostly work, but you will never be sure that the next change you make to your code won't cause it to break.

Comment: And even if it does work, making copies of the DLLs puts you in a position where any time you update the installed Notes code you will have to remember to copy again, otherwise you may end up with incompatibile versions and this well be very, very difficult to debug. And even if you do copy again, we go back to the initial point: you're in an unsupported configuraiton, and it might have worked before, but now the updated DLLs might not. Nobody tests this configuration except you, and IBM won't help you if it doesn't work - even if it worked before the update.

Comment: Sorry for the confusing in my last post, my question in my last note was: in my java web application(eclipse), I only need Notes.jar (64bit) file to be added to my java application, and add my local path to point to nlsxbe.dll, why do I need to install Domino server 64bit to my Java web application server?

Comment: There is no such thing as a 64 bit Notes.jar. The jar file is the same for both the 64 bit JVM and the 32 bit JVM. (I'm sorry that I may have contributed to your confusion about this due to my mention of the OpenNTF project and their version of the API. Please forget that I mentioned that!)  The thing that matters is that if the JVM is 32 bit, then nlsxbe.dll and all the other Notes DLLs must be from a 32 bit Notes or Domino installation. If the JVM is 64 bit, then the DLLs must be from a 64 bit Domino server installation because there is no such thing as a 64 bit Notes client installation.

Comment: Thanks for you clarification.. but since the Notes.jar is sitting on my local notes client(I have Lotus designer access), and I can get this file and load it to my java project by eclipse. that is why I think it has nothing to do with Domino server since this file is not located on server side. That is why I am confusing. So to make it simple, if I have Lotus notes 64bits client in my machine, then I can get the Notes.jar from it, the bottom line is the Lotus Notes 64bits, not Domino server 64bits, please correct me if I still misunderstood it. thanks

Comment: There is no 64 bit Lotus Notes client. It does not exist. This is why I am telling you that the only way you can get 64 bit versions of the DLLs  is to install the 64 bit Lotus Domino Server for Window.

Comment: Sorry for the confusing, now I am clear that there is no 64bits Notes.jar at all. so my question is where should I get the Notes.jar from? should I get it from physical server machine which has Domino 64 bits server installed? currently, I get it from my local machine at: C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\Lotus\Notes\jvm\lib\ext. TO make it more clear, should I install Domino 64bits server on the server machine which has Java web run and get the Notes.jar file from this server machine? Do I also need to add path on my environment var to point to:nlsxbe.dll file on my local machine?

Comment: When I add Java codes to connect Lotus Notes database, I must write the java source in eclipse on my local machine and run it in local, so even I can copy the Notes.jar from somewhere in Domino server(64bits) machine to my local somewhere, is that going to work?

Comment: Please understand this: the notes.jar and the DLL files are two very different things. The notes.jar is Java code. There is no such thing as a 64 bit or 32 bit version. It is the same for both bit sizes. The JVM does not care. You can copy any version of Notes.jar that you want. But the DLL files are C code. They ARE different on 32 and 64 bit. If your JVM is 64 bit, then you must use 64 bit DLLs. But you cannot just copy the DLLs. They MUST be properly installed as part of a full Notes or Domino package. And since you require 64 bits, the ONLY option is to install the 64 bit Domino Server.

Comment: I do not wish to be rude, but I have answered this for you many times, each time with the same information. Please stop asking about copying files. You cannot just do that. It is not supported. If you want to call APIs in Notes.jar from a 64 bit JVM on Windows, then you MUST install the 64 bit Domino Server for Windows on the machine where the code runs. This is true for a dev machine with Eclipse. It is true for a production web application server that runs your code. Your other alternative is to switch to using NCSO.jar. I'm not going to repeat it again. You can either believe me, or not.

Comment: Thanks for your clarification again, sorry for asking so many questions. OK, let me clarify it again. My Java web application is running in 3 development (server) environments and one production(server) environment. All those server machines should be installed Domino 64 bits server on it, right? plus, since I first develop and test my java code is in my local machine, so my local machine also needs the Domino Server(64bits) installed, right? you mentioned 64bits DLL file, is it nlsxe.dll I need to add in Path environment variable, right? are there any other DLL files?

Comment: I follow this info to get Notes.jar file: http://thinkgreat.blogspot.ca/2007/08/developing-java-for-domino-in-eclipse.html, you can see from that note, it shows where to get Notes.jar. I also found somethere which I also need to add Path as windows environment variable to point to of "C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\Lotus\Notes which is nlsxbe.dll in my local. I think the point is the nslxbe.dll must get from Domino 64bits server, right?

Comment: this article is interesting: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/lotus/library/notes-plugin-eclipse/

Comment: Yes, that article is interesting but you said above that this is a Java web application, so I don't think the information about Eclipse plugins is relevant.

Comment: "All those server machines should be installed Domino 64 bits server on it, right?"  Yes.

Comment: "so my local machine also needs the Domino Server(64bits) installed, right?"  Yes.

Comment: "you mentioned 64bits DLL file, is it nlsxe.dll I need to add in Path environment variable, right? are there any other DLL files?" You need ALL of the Notes core API DLLs. The installation program for the 64 bit Domino Server should put the appropriate folder on your system path.

Comment: "I follow this info to get Notes.jar file: thinkgreat.blogspot.ca/2007/08/…" That link was broken. I don't know what it says. The best idea is to get Notes.jar from the same version of Notes or Domino that you have installed.

Comment: "I think the point is the nslxbe.dll must get from Domino 64bits server, right?" Yes. And ALL of the other DLLs. You must install the server. The installer should put the correct folder on your system path. The only reason you might need to add it to your path in Eclipse is if your project is somehow configured to not use the system path.

Comment: Thanks for your clarification, I donot think my notes admin will set that for me. So now, I think I should use CORBA IIOP to do it since I do not need to install anything. I found this link:http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/lotus/library/ls-Java_access_2/ . basically, I only need to add c:\lotus\domino\data\domino\java\NCSO.jar to my java eclipse library and connect domino server remotely. I tried Session s = NotesFactory.createSession("devs2:63148"); String p = s.getCommonUserName(); and tried to connect database, but I got: "Anonymous cannot open datavbase xxxx",

Comment: I also tried to add userID and password in NotesFactory.createSession("devs2:63148", "sjon", "sjon12"); I always get invalid userid and password. Somebody also had this issue at: http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/nd85forum.nsf/DateAllThreadedWeb/BF0878D7D8BDD0EA85257D2C006D610A?opendocument&login but there is no solution yet. The ACL of notes database has default access of Editor which should work, and the server document in address book is setup as the instruction url I posted above. any idea?

Comment: Create a session by using an individual userid and password is not good even it is working,  since my notes database default access is "Editor", so everybody can access to it. so idea way to access it without needing any userid and password. any idea?

Comment: Use createSession(host,"",""). Note that the server must be set up to allow anonymous sessions on the DIIOP port, otherwise this will not work. Your server admin can check this in the Domino Directory - Server document - Ports tab - Internet Ports tab - DIIOP tab.

Comment: I just checked the Address Book of my Domino server which contains my notes database, it seems the Anonymous is set, this is what I can see, under Server document, Ports\Internet Ports tab\DIIOP tab, I can see the Authentication  options: Name & password: Yes, Anonymous: Yes, Client certificate: N/A, SSL port status: Enabled, TCP/IP port status: Enabled, I also tried to change "Name & password" option from "Yes" to "No"?, but there is no difference, are there anywhere else I should change from server document?

Comment: Problem has been resolved, the issue is that the database ACL has an Anonymous entry with No Access. after changed it to Editor, then it is working well now. Thank you so much for your help, Richard,

Comment: I'm glad it's working. Could you please upvote and accept my answer? I wouldn't normally ask outright, but considering how I've engaged with you to follow up in these comments, I do think it deserves that.

Comment: Actually, I had tried to mark it as Answered by clicking vote tab, but can not find any function there. if you can , please mark it as answered, I do appreciate all of your time and posts to answer my question in this thread, thank you again.