# Cannot find nlsxbe in java library path

Tags: java, lotus-domino, lotus

I'm trying to load library files of Notes. By setting the path of notes user data folder `nlsxbe.dll` under `C:\notes` and notes installation folder `C:\notes\data`.

I set my enviromental variables like this. `C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_131\bin;C:\notes;C\notes\data;` But cannot find the notes library still throwing a error `java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no nlsxbe in java.library.path` Any tips or trick to solve this problem? :)

I also add my external jar from `C:\notes\jvm\lib\ext`

Screenshot:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Maybe your problem is similar to this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27868284/java-lang-unsatisfiedlinkerror-c-program-files-x86-ibm-lotus-notes-nlsxbe-dl

Comment: And, for what it's worth: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21201491

Answer (score 0):

The native libraries can be added using environment parameters. I [wrote about it](https://www.wissel.net/blog/2014/07/adventures-with-vertx-64bit-and-the-ibm-notes-client.html) in a slightly different context. What you need to do is to add 2 environment variables:

```
SET DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=C:\notes
SET LD_LIBRARY_PATH=C:\notes
```

That should do the trick