# could not load 32 bit nlsxbe.dll on AMD 64 bit

Tags: java, java-8, lotus-notes, 32bit-64bit

I am trying to send lotus notes email through java code using notesfactory which uses local notes.jar file

The code i written in eclipse worked perfectly. In eclipse but when i exported executable runnable jar..

The code throws error as

Cant load nlsxbe.dll 32 bit on IA 64 bit.

The machine i am using is 64 bit but i have installed 32 bit jdk..and added that path into system variables.

The error throws at line

NotesThread.setinitThread();

Its working in eclipse.

I cannot use ncso.jar as our client will not allow to do so.

The code i am using

```
NotesThread.sinitThread();
Session    session=NotesFactory.createSessionWithFullAccess(password);
Database      db=session.getDatabase(null,nsfFile);
If(!db.open())
{
db.open();
}
```

Comment: I see that you say you have a 32-bit JRE installed and on the path, but are you sure you are running your code with it? The error message you mention is what I would expect to see if a 64-bit JVM is attempting to load the 32-bit DLL. See this old question (and my answer) for confirmation: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27868284/java-lang-unsatisfiedlinkerror-c-program-files-x86-ibm-lotus-notes-nlsxbe-dl

Comment: On my pc both 32 bit and 64 bit jdk are installed. I have set 32 bit jdk as java build environment...

Comment: Thank you rechards, uninstalling 64 bit jdk worked for me